# Why won't this c++ lamba function compile?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Why does this fail to compile:

```
int myVar = 0;
myVar ? []()->void{} : []()->void{};
```

with following error msg:

> Error 2   error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'red_black_core::`anonymous-namespace'::< lambda1>' to red_black_core::anonymous-namespace::< lambda0>

While this complies correctly:

```
void left()
{}
void right()
{}

int myVar = 0;
myVar ? left() : right();
```

Comment: What compiler do you use and what are the warning/errors it gives?

Comment: As usual, what's the error message?

Comment: First, whitespace is free. Second, have you tried without the `->void` ? I find that telling compilers more than they need to know can make them unhappy.

Comment: @Kate did you first try your answer or you just said what first came to your head without even checking if it is correct what you are trying to say?

Comment: @There - a comment, not an answer. If I tested it and it worked I would have given you an answer saying take 'em out. A quick suggestion that might or might not help, I gave you a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules for conditional operator in the draft n3225 says at one point

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either
>   has (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be
>   applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise,
>   the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original
>   operands for the remainder of this section.

Up to that point, every other alternative (like, convert one to the other operand) failed, so we will now do what that paragraph says. The conversions we will apply are determined by overload resolution by transforming `a ? b : c` into `operator?(a, b, c)` (an imaginary function call to a so-named function). If you look what the candidates for the imaginary `operator?` are, you find (among others)

> For every type T , where T is a pointer, pointer-to-member, or scoped enumeration type, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> T operator?(bool, T , T );
> ```

And this includes a candidate for which `T` is the type `void(*)()`. This is important, because lambda expressions yield an object of a class that can be converted to such a type. The spec says

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

The lambda expressions can't be convert to any other of the parameter types listed, which means overload resolution succeeds, finds a single `operator?` and will convert both lambda expressions to function pointers. The remainder of the conditional opreator section will then proceed as usual, now having two branches for the conditional operator having the same type.

That's why also your first version is OK, and why GCC is right accepting it. However I don't really understand why you show the second version at all - as others explained, it's doing something different and it's not surprising that it works while the other doesn't (on your compiler). Next time, best try not to include useless code into the question.

Comment: Meh. Throwing standardese out there without explaining it doesn't seem all that helpful to me!

Comment: @Tomalak, ohh you are right! I've now elaborated on everything.

Comment: @Tomalak Note that it's *not* sufficient to just show that both branches can be converted to the same type. For example, both `ios *x = &cin;` and `ios *y = &cout;` is valid, but still `myVar ? &cin : &cout` is invalid. That's why I quoted the draft. So I wanted to state *more* explanation by quoting the spec, instead of less by omitting details. If the questioner doesn't understand something, he can ask and I can clarify. If I just state some over-general thing, he will have to believe it until he hits a similar case where the over-general explanation wouldn't fit. That wouldn't be good.

Comment: as for useless code... It is just for explanational purpouses. Just a shell, which I my opinion is the right thing to do. Why would I provide my entire code? It would just distract reader from a real problem.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando, I have the impression that in your second example you wanted to try: `myVar ? left : right` to get a function pointer out of the expression similar to how you wanted to get a lambda function out of the first expression. Is that true?

Answer (score 9):

The return type of the ?: operator has to be deduced from it's two operands, and the rules for determining this type are quite complex. Lambdas don't satisfy them because they can't be converted to each other. So when the compiler tries to work out what the result of that ?: is, then there can't be a result, because those two lambdas aren't convertible to each other.

However, when you try to compute the functions, then you actually *called* them, but you didn't *call* the lambdas. So when you call the functions, they both have void, so the return type of ?: is void.

This

```
void left()
{}
void right()
{}

int myVar = 0;
myVar ? left() : right();
```

is equivalent to

```
int myVar = 0;
myVar ? [](){}() : [](){}();
```

Note the extra () on the end- I actually called the lambda.

What you had originally is equivalent to

```
compiler_deduced_type var;
if (myVar)
    var = [](){};
else
    var = [](){};
```

But- no type exists that can be both lambdas. The compiler is well within it's rights to make both lambdas different types.

EDIT:

I remembered something. In the latest Standard draft, lambdas with no captures can be implicitly converted into function pointers of the same signature. That is, in the above code, compiler_deduced_type could be void(*)(). However, I know for a fact that MSVC does not include this behaviour because that was not defined at the time that they implemented lambdas. This is likely why GCC allows it and MSVC does not- GCC's lambda support is substantially newer than MSVC's.

Comment: @DeadMG so why does it compile with GCC?

Comment: @There: How the hell should I know? Question doesn't ask that.

Comment: @DeadMG Well I've just ask you so the question does ask __that__. So maybe from different side: Who is right VS or GCC according to the standard?

Comment: @There: Go post a new question for it. That's not this question. You asked why your sample fails to compile, and I've told you in fair detail. I answered the question as it's posted. If you want to ask more, go ask a new question.

Comment: Couldn't both lambdas be implicitly converted to `std::function<void()>` by the `?:` operator?

Comment: @FredOverflow: No. The std::function<void()> can be constructed from both of them. That's not the same at all. The lambdas do not have a conversion operator to std::function<void()>. More importantly, the ?: has a single return type- *even if* the context doesn't demand it.

Comment: @FredOverflow: In other words, yes.
@DeadMG: +1 for the last paragraph in your answer.
@Thereisnothingwecando: GCC. As DeadMG says in his answer, as of the latest draft (and remember, it's not a fixed standard yet! it's still changing and evolving slightly) the behaviour is valid, and GCC supports it. VS doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Because every lambda is a unique type. It is basically syntactic sugar for a functor, and two separately implemented functors aren't the same type, even if they contain identical code.

The standard does specify that lambdas can be converted to function pointers if they don't capture anything, but that rule was added after MSVC's lambda support was implemented.

With that rule, however, two lambdas can be converted to the same type, and so I believe your code would be valid with a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets compile just fine with GCC 4.5.2.

Maybe your compiler has no (or partial/broken) support to C++0x features such as lambda?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fail to compile. It works just fine. <strike>You probably don't have C++0x enabled in your compiler.</strike>

**Edit:**
An error message has now been added to the original question! It seems that you do have C++0x support, but that it is not complete in your compiler. This is not surprising.

The code is still valid C++0x, but I recommend only using C++0x features when you really have to, until it's standardised and there is full support across a range of toolchains. You have a viable C++03 alternative that you gave in your answer, and I suggest using it for the time being.

**Possible alternative explanation:**

Also note that you probably didn't write what you actually meant to write. `[]()->void{}` is a lambda. `[]()->void{}()` executes the lambda and evaluates to its result. Depending what you're doing with this result, your problem could be that the result of calling your lambda is `void`, and you can't do much with `void`.

Comment: His compiler doesn't have an option to turn it off. The error message doesn't mention malformed syntax, it mentions specifically lambdas.

Comment: @DeadMG: So it now seems. He had not posted his error message when I wrote this answer. Edited to update.