# Calling overloaded constructor from constructor initialisation list

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, initializer-list, constructor-overloading

In the code below, my intent is to call one of two overloaded constructors for the `kap` (class `opacity`) based on what arguments are passed to the object of class `material`:

```
class opacity{
 private:
  int mode;
  double kap_const;
  double kappa_array[10][10];

 public:
  opacity(double constkap);  // picking the constructor sets the mode
  opacity(char* Datafile);
  double value(double T, double P); // will return a constant or interpolate
};

opacity::opacity(double constkap):mode(1){
  kap_const = constkap;
}

opacity::opacity(char* Datafile):mode(2){
  // read file into kappa_array...
}

class Matter {
 public:
  Matter(int i, double k, char* filename); // many more values are actually passed
  opacity kap;
  int x;  // dummy thing
  // more variables, call some functions
};

Matter::Matter(int i, double k, char * filename)
 :x(k>0? this->kap(x): this->kap(filename) ) {
  // ... rest of initialisation
 }
```

This is however not working:

```
test.cpp: In constructor 'Matter::Matter(int, double, char*)':
test.cpp:32:21: error: no match for call to '(opacity) (void*&)'
test.cpp:32:42: error: no match for call to '(opacity) (char*&)'
test.cpp:32:44: error: no matching function for call to 'opacity::opacity()'
test.cpp:32:44: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:20:1: note: opacity::opacity(char*)
test.cpp:20:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:16:1: note: opacity::opacity(double)
test.cpp:16:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:4:7: note: opacity::opacity(const opacity&)
test.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The first thing I had tried,

```
Matter::Matter(int i, double k, char * filename)
 :kap(k>0? k: filename) {   // use k<0 as a flag to read from filename
  // ... rest of initialisation
}
```

also failed, because "the result of a ternary operator always has to be the same type" for compile-time reasons, as pointed out in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693629/ternary-operator?answertab=votes#tab-top) (although they were not explained there, it seems).

Now, the inelegant solution would be to also overload the `Matter` constructor based on the arguments that the `kap` constructor should receive, but this is (1) very inelegant, especially since the `Matter` constructor takes many variables and performs many actions (so a lot of code would be duplicated just to vary the `kap` part of the constructor initialisation list), and (2) this can get out of hand if there is another class used with `Matter` that also has different constructors: for *M* classes with *N* c'tors, one ends up with *N*^ *M* combinations...

Would someone have a suggestion or a work-around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to add a special constructor to `opacity`.  Either one that takes an int and filename, or a default constructor so you can assign it in the body of `Matter`s constructor.

Comment: Why don't you pass the opacity kap as a constructor argument ? You can use the ternary operator before calling the constructor, then create an opacity object (on the heap probably) and pass a pointer to it in the matter constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, did you mean what Johannes Schaub wrote? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @John If I understand your suggestion properly, there is a caveat: "the user" (ok, this is just me...) should have to play only with the `Matter` object he creates, and not have to create an `opacity` instance separately---it gets used just by `Matter`. This intent may not have been clear from my use of `public`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If opacity has a copy constructor, you could accomplish this in the initialization list, avoiding a default constructor, but at the cost of a copy:

```
  Matter::Matter(int i, double k, char * filename)
     :kap( ( 0 < k ) ? opacity(k) : opacity( filename ) ) { ... }
```

Comment: Same as Johannes Schaub's answer, just more compact. Thanks.

Comment: @Labbedudl : **Not** the same -- Johannes' answer uses default-initialization followed by assignment, this one uses copy-initialization. I.e., this one is (theoretically) more efficient and doesn't require that `opacity` be default constructable.

Comment: @ildjarn: it's theoretically more efficient, and with RVO, actually more efficient.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for the clarification! I will pick this answer because of the greater efficiency.

Comment: @Labbedudl, realize that it requires a properly working copy constructor for `opacity`. If `opacity` is expensive to copy it wouldn't be more efficient at all. I doubt that it's a concern in your case though.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to live with adding a default constructor to `opacity` (which perhaps sets mode to `0` to indicate an invalid mode) and assign to `kap` in the constructor body.

```
Matter::Matter(int i, double k, char * filename) {
  if(k > 0)
    kap = opacity(k);
  else
    kap = opacity(filename);
}
```

The parameter `k` is a runtime value. It is not possible to make types and overloading result depend on runtime values.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was imaging one could have the `opacity` constructor called only from the initialisation list...

Answer (score 1):

To obviate copy overhead, and assuming you have a C++0x compiler, you could give opacity a [move constructor](http://www.google.com/search?q=move%20constructor) and have a static function provide an instance of `opacity` based on your logic and initialize your `kap` member with the returned temporary `opacity`.

You'd probably want to make `kappa_array` some pointer like `auto_ptr<double>`. Though if this data is used in a tight-loop, the savings from moveability may be dubious compared to the cost of locality and dereferencing the pointer.

```
opacity& get_opacity(double k, char * filename) {
    if(k > 0)
        return opacity(k);
    else
        return opacity(filename);
}

Matter::Mater(int i, double k, char * filename)
    : kap(get_opacity(k, filename) {
   //...
}

opacity::opacity(opacity&& other)
    : mode(other.mode),
      kap_const(other.kap_const),
      kappa_array(std::move(kappa_array)) { }
```

Please don't test me on this, I'm pretty new with move semantics and rvalue references myself...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a ternary operator to select function overrides because the result of the operator only has a single type. In the case where the different branches have different types, they will be coerced to the result type or there will be a compile time error. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Result_type

It couldn't really be any other way. Types need to be known by the compiler at compile time, but the result of the operation isn't known until run time.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this too, that the compiler apparently must know at compile time. Why is this, though?

Comment: @Labbedudl, the compiler generates a single call to a single function when it compiles the code. It must know which function signature matches at that time. If you need to choose between two different function calls, they must be made explicit in two different branches of code.